# what are the packages that should be installed in play on linux?

Tags: playonlinux

what are the packages that should be installed in play on linux? so I would have a windows like environment for gaming without all the fuss

Answer (score 2):

With playonlinux, you shouldn't really have to install any other packages per se, it's more about installing games; playonlinux should prompt you to download anything it needs to help you.